# Apply onclick rule on div with exceptions

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run a javascript function everytime a user clicks anywhere on the page (div "maincontent") EXCEPT on any of the two buttons (div "btnNew" and "btnRegister"). How can I do that? My first approach doesn't work.

```
<div id="mainContent" class="content" onclick="hidePopUps(document.this)">
    [...]
    <div id="btnNew" class="btn-welcome" onclick="showRegister()">New user</div>
    <div id="btnRegister" class="btn-welcome" onclick="showLogin()">Existing user</div>
    [...]
</div>

function hidePopUps(element) {
    if(element == $("#mainContent")) {
       hideLogin();
       hideRegister();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things work the way you want I would:

1. change your onlick events:

   a. you don't need `hidePopUps(document.this)`, just `hidePopUps(this)`

   b. in `showRegister()` and `showLogin()` put 'event' variable inside brackets to pass it to these functions to avoid bubbling
2. prevent bubbling when buttons are clicked in called functions
3. use `id` to check if container was clicked: should read as `if(element.id == 'mainContent') {` instead of `if(element == $("#mainContent")) {`

So your code could look like:

```
<div id="mainContent" class="content" onclick="hidePopUps(this)">
    <div>some content before</div>
    <div id="btnNew" class="btn-welcome" onclick="showRegister(event)">New user</div>
    <div id="btnRegister" class="btn-welcome" onclick="showLogin(event)">Existing user</div>
    <div>some content after</div>
</div>

function showRegister(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    ...
}

function showLogin(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    ...
}

function hidePopUps(element) {
    if(element.id == 'mainContent') {
       hideLogin();
       hideRegister();
    }
}
```

Check out this fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/pdy8y06z/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with jQuery and the `:not()` selector:

```
$(":not(body):not(html):not(#btnNew):not(#btnRegister)").click(function() {
    // the :not(body) and :not(html) are to prevent it
    // from setting off additional event listeners because
    // everything is on top of the html and body tags

    // ... handler here
});
```

This should select everything but those two buttons.

See a working example at [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/0b9b5n9f/5/).